# how to rewire this 3 prong to 2 prong

Tags: electrical, socket

During an inspection in this house which was built in 1913, we found this outlet that is a 3 prong with an open ground.  I pulled it out to replace it with a 2 prong but am not sure what wires go where.  I believe the top right wire on the socket is black, so there's black, white and red.  I also think there's one other 3 prong socket on that wall that I'm guessing this runs to.  I had a handyman with some electrical experience look at it but he wasn't quite sure so hopefully, someone can shed some light on how to do this.  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I started to write an answer, but this one may be more complicated. Short answer: Install a GFCI which will provide protection comparable to a ground wire **even without an actual ground wire connected**. If labelled correctly, that is 100% legal. However, the black/red (== two hots) with only one white/neutral makes me wonder if this is a split (half-switched, half-always-on) pair of receptacles, which complicates things a bit. **Is one (or both) receptacle controlled by a switch?**

Comment: Looks half-switched to me?  Replacing with a 2-prong outlet is legal, just be sure to break-away the tab on the hot side if it’s held switched.

Comment: No switch that I'm aware of.  The room has a ceiling fan on a switch, but that's the only switch in the room.

Comment: The second wire on the right is probably the hot feed to the next outlet.

Comment: @bib But then where is the *neutral* feed to the next outlet?

Comment: @manassehkatz hmmm. Good point. Curious to see the wires in the other outlet boxes on the line.

Comment: @geoffswartz a) Is there a connector between the black wire & red wire screws? b) If you connect only black or only red, does the outlet work and do the other outlets in the room work?

Comment: The tab *looks* broken on the existing outlet in the picture.

Comment: @Tyson Could be this **was** switched at one time and instead of putting in a jumper or pigtail here to connect the two screws, the original switch wires were spliced together (and then hidden inside a junction box "somewhere").

Comment: @manassehkatz that’s entirely possible, and likely the case if OP doesn’t know of a switch.  It would be interesting to open up any switch in the room and find out if there is evidence of this.

Comment: @Tyson Assuming that **is** the case, would the proper thing to do if you wanted to put in a no-ground-wire-GFCI be to pigtail black/red together or to use just one and cap the other?

Comment: @manassehkatz personally I’d cap the red and stick with black and white.  I would not combine them.  While a GFCI is one solution that is a small j-box, If OP already has purchased his 2-blade receptacle with no ground, I’d just use that.

Comment: @manassehkatz use black and cap red.  Don't join them, that creates a parallel route, and you should never parallel...  unless you are doing feeder so large that no MCM/kcmil sized wire is available to do it in one...and special apparatus on the feed side.

Comment: @Harper & Tyson  - I thought so, but figured I would ask. I would think that a GFCI would be useful here both for safety and because it would allow proper use of 3-prong devices - e.g., plug in a laptop power cord without a 2/3 cheater.

Comment: Yes indeed, if you can deprecate the red or black wire, the win is that you can *then* fit a GFCI+receptacle combo device.  Assuming the circuit isn't *already* GFCI protected upstream, of course.  That's hard to test because with no ground, a GFCI tester will not work.

Comment: Of course maybe there is a ground.  I see a metal box.  That could be armored cable feeding it. Not supposed to use that for grounds today, but may be grandfathered.

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the back of the box please?

Comment: Thanks for all the input.  I just decided to end up having an electrician friend come and take care of it for me.